# expected dense_input to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a model on features i extracted from some images, model trains fine, but when i try model.predict it gives me this error.
" expected dense_input to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)"
i have the knowledge about the shape of the input but the error is just weird. it makes no sense to me right now i tried to print the shape of the input i am giving to model.predict and its fine.

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation

trainX = np.array(train_set)

trainY = np.array(train_labels)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=1200, batch_size=2, verbose=2)
model.save('my_model.h5') 

for i in np.array(test_set):
    print(i.shape)
    dataPrediction = model.predict(i)
    print (dataPrediction, '<--- Predicted number')
    print (test_labels[i],' <-- Correct answer \n')
```

print(i.shape) gives me (7,)
yet it gives me error
Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your model expects an array of samples, but you're giving it a single sample at a time.

It therefore treated each feature in your sample as an individual sample of shape `(1,)`, which didn't make sense to it since you presumably had 7 features and it therefore expected a sample of shape `(7,)`.

You can just do `model.predict(np.array(test_set))`.

Comment: thanks but i have another question it gives me output in the form of array. what if i dont want to get output of the entire test_set i want output of a single index.....thats what i was trying to do previously

Comment: [[ 5.08247223e+02]
 [ 4.27124237e+02]
 [ 1.48102112e+02]
 [ 4.79016174e+02]
 [ 3.17654358e+02]
 [ 3.85800659e+02]
 [ 2.42645782e+02]
 [ 4.85515808e+02]
 [ 4.90140198e+02]
 [ 3.21222168e+02]
 [ 5.07919434e+02]
 [ 7.01163879e+02]
 [ 4.37445679e+02]
 [ 5.34403015e+02]
 [ 2.09943771e+02]
 [ 6.28523560e+02]
 [ 2.31655823e+02]
 [ 3.22497009e+02]
 [ 6.75255371e+02]
 [ 2.18437088e+02]
 [ 2.72339539e+02]
 [ 2.97595154e+02]
 [ 7.60216980e+02]] <--- Predicted number

Comment: The simplest way for you to do that would be to run `predict` on the whole array and then just take the results one by one. If you really want to run `predict` on single samples, try `i.reshape(1, 7)`. Also, please don't post chunks of data/code in comments.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
dataPrediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(i,axis=0))
```

Comment: It worked for me! I was getting this error: : Error when checking input: expected dense_4_input to have shape (1714,) but got array with shape (1,)